# Using "curve" to plot a function: a tricky expression?

Tags: r, plot, vectorization, curve

My question concerns something that should be fairly simple, but I can't make it work. What I mean is you can calculate `x` and `y` and then plot them with the `plot` function. But can this be done using the `curve` function?

I want to plot the following `R` function `f2`:

```
n <- 1
m <- 2
f2 <- function(x) min(x^n, x^(-m))
```

But this code fails:

```
curve(f2, 0, 10)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Even if you do not include `m` and `n` as arguments to your function `f2` as suggested by @Maurits-Evers, you should define `m` and `n` in your question so the answers can be more easily compared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been hinted at, the main reason why the call to `curve` fails is because `curve` requires a vectorized function (in this case feed in a vector of results and get out a vector of results), while your f2() function only inputs and outputs a scalar. You can vectorize your f2 on the fly with `Vectorize`

```
n <- 1
m <- 2

f2 <- function(x) min(x^n, x^(-m))
curve(Vectorize(f2)(x), 0, 10)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to use vectorised `pmin` instead of `min` (take a look at `?pmin` to understand the difference)

```
f2 = function(x, n = 1, m = 2) {
    pmin(x^n, x^(-m))
}

curve(f2, from = 0, to = 10)
```

On a side note, I would make `n` and `m` arguments of `f2` to avoid global variables.

[image]

---

### Update

To plot `f2` for *different* arguments `n` and `m` you would do

```
curve(f2(x, n = 2, m = 3), from = 0, to = 10)
```

[image]

Comment: @PA6OTA If this solution works for you, remember to mark the checkbox to indicate a working solution.

Comment: A followup question: how do you use "curve" if your function has more arguments (n,m)? That is, f2 is defined as a function of 3 arguments, but I want to give particular values to n and m.

Comment: @PA6OTA Please see my updated answer. You would specify e.g. `f2(x, n = 2, m = 3)` inside `curve` to plot `f2` with `n=2` and `m=3`.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `curve` function needed or would this work?

```
n <- 1 # assumption
m <- 2 # assumption

f2 <- function(x) min(x^n, x^(-m))

x.range <- seq(0, 10, by=.1) 
y.results <- sapply(x.range, f2) # Apply a Function over a List or Vector
# plot(x.range, y.results) old answer
plot(x.range, y.results, type="l") # improvement per @alistaire
```

[image]

Comment: Try `type = 'l'` in `plot`

Comment: Adam, this of course works but "curve" would be easier!

Comment: @PA6OTA Agree. You should accept the answer from Maurits Evers. (Edit: Sorry, I see you already selected a different one.)

Comment: @Adam yes it's a good answer but the "Vectorize" one is more applicable to other situations, I guess.